# How to check NaN in gradients in Tensorflow when updating?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, deep-learning, mathematical-optimization

All,

When you train a large model with large amount samples, some samples may be cause NaN gradient when parameter updating.

And I want to find these samples out. And meanwhile I don't want this batch samples' gradient to update model's parameter, because it may be cause model's parameter being NaN.

So dose anyone have good idea to deal with this problem?

My code is like below:

```
    # Create an optimizer.
    params = tf.trainable_variables()
    opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(1e-3)
    gradients = tf.gradients(self.loss, params)

    max_gradient_norm = 10
    clipped_gradients, self.gradient_norms = tf.clip_by_global_norm(gradients,
                                                     max_gradient_norm)

    self.optimizer = opt.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, params))
```

Answer (score 10):

You can check whether your gradients have NaN by `tf.check_numerics`:

```
grad_check = tf.check_numerics(clipped_gradients)
with tf.control_dependencies([grad_check]):
  self.optimizer = opt.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, params))
```

The `grad_check` would throw `InvalidArgument` if clipped_gradients is NaN or infinity.

The `tf.control_dependencies` makes sure that the `grad_check` is evaluated before applying the gradients.

Also see `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()`.

Comment: Thank you so much. But I have a question again. When I add tf.add_check_numerics_ops() in my code, I get a Out of Memory error. And remove this line, everything is okay. My model is really large, so tf.add_check_numerics_ops() will allocate more GPU memory for check ops?

Comment: There is a tensor copy in the kernel of `tf.check_numerics`: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/kernels/check_numerics_op.cc#L60. So just add a couple checks using `tf.check_numerics`. Extra cautions need to be taken if you would like to use `tf.add_check_numerics_ops()` which runs `tf.check_numerics` for all floating-typed tensors.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`tf.is_nan`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/is_nan) in combination with [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to only execute the rest of your code if the loss is not NaN.