# TensorFlow print input tensors?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm building a TF training program and attempting to diagnose some issues we are seeing with it.  Root problem is the gradients are always nan.  This is against the CIFAR10 data set (we wrote our own program from scratch to ensure we understand all of the mechanics properly).

Its too much code to post here; so it is here: https://github.com/drcrook1/CIFAR10

At this point we are fairly certain the issue is not the learning rate (we took that sucker down to 1e-25 and still got nans; we also simplified the network to a single mlp layer).

What we think is likely happening is the values being read in by the input pipeline are wrong; therefor we want to print the values from a TFRecordReader pipeline to double check that it is in fact reading and decoding the samples properly.  As you know, you can only print a TF value if you know its name or have it captured as a variable; so that brings up the point; how does one print an input tensor from a mini batch?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: just to make sure: you want people to search through your github folder with 10 files and 2 notebooks to fix your error?

Comment: I feel like there may be a question in here which simply involves how to get something to help with your debugging, but please create a [mcve] for it rather than make people go through your whole folder. The larger debugging task is way too much to ask.

Comment: Sorry about the full folder inclusion; I ended up solving the issue however and posting the answer.  I probably should have simply noted which files were important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out you can return examples and labels as operations and then simply print them during graph execution.

```
def create_sess_ops():
'''
Creates and returns operations needed for running
a tensorflow training session
'''
GRAPH = tf.Graph()
with GRAPH.as_default():
    examples, labels = Inputs.read_inputs(CONSTANTS.RecordPaths,
                                          batch_size=CONSTANTS.BATCH_SIZE,
                                          img_shape=CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE,
                                          num_threads=CONSTANTS.INPUT_PIPELINE_THREADS)
    examples = tf.reshape(examples, [CONSTANTS.BATCH_SIZE, CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[0],
                                     CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[1], CONSTANTS.IMAGE_SHAPE[2]])
    logits = Vgg3CIFAR10.inference(examples)
    loss = Vgg3CIFAR10.loss(logits, labels)
    OPTIMIZER = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(CONSTANTS.LEARNING_RATE)
    #OPTIMIZER = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(CONSTANTS.LEARNING_RATE)
    gradients = OPTIMIZER.compute_gradients(loss)
    apply_gradient_op = OPTIMIZER.apply_gradients(gradients)
    gradients_summary(gradients)
    summaries_op = tf.summary.merge_all()
    return [apply_gradient_op, summaries_op, loss, logits, examples, labels], GRAPH
```

Notice in the above code we use the input queue runners to grab examples and inputs and feed into the graph.  We then return examples and labels as operations along side all of our other operations which can then be used during a session run;

```
def main():
'''
Run and Train CIFAR 10
'''
print('starting...')
ops, GRAPH = create_sess_ops()
total_duration = 0.0
with tf.Session(graph=GRAPH) as SESSION:
    COORDINATOR = tf.train.Coordinator()
    THREADS = tf.train.start_queue_runners(SESSION, COORDINATOR)
    SESSION.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    SUMMARY_WRITER = tf.summary.FileWriter('Tensorboard/' + CONSTANTS.MODEL_NAME)
    GRAPH_SAVER = tf.train.Saver()

    for EPOCH in range(CONSTANTS.EPOCHS):
        duration = 0
        error = 0.0
        start_time = time.time()
        for batch in range(CONSTANTS.MINI_BATCHES):
            _, summaries, cost_val, prediction = SESSION.run(ops)
            print(np.where(np.isnan(prediction)))
            print(prediction[0])
            print(labels[0])
            plt.imshow(examples[0])       
            plt.show()         
            error += cost_val
        duration += time.time() - start_time
        total_duration += duration
        SUMMARY_WRITER.add_summary(summaries, EPOCH)
        print('Epoch %d: loss = %.2f (%.3f sec)' % (EPOCH, error, duration))
        if EPOCH == CONSTANTS.EPOCHS - 1 or error < 0.005:
            print(
                'Done training for %d epochs. (%.3f sec)' % (EPOCH, total_duration)
            )
            break
```

Notice in the above code we take the examples and labels operations and we can now print a variety of things.  We print out if anything is nan; along with that we print the prediction array itself, the label and we even use matplot lib to plot an example image in each mini batch.

This is exactly what I was looking to do.  I needed to do this to verify my issues.  The root cause was due to labels being read incorrectly therefor producing infinite gradients; because the labels did not match the examples.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at the tf.Print operator?
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Print

If you add this to your graph with an input from one of the nodes you suspect of causing the problem, you should be able to see the results in stderr.

You may also find the check_numerics operator useful for debugging your problem:

[How to check NaN in gradients in Tensorflow when updating?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701712/how-to-check-nan-in-gradients-in-tensorflow-when-updating)

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an ideal use-case for the official [TensorFlow Debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger).

From the first example on the page:

```py
from tensorflow.python import debug as tf_debug

sess = tf_debug.LocalCLIDebugWrapperSession(sess)
sess.add_tensor_filter("has_inf_or_nan", tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan)
```

From your description, it seems that you too need the `tf_debug.has_inf_or_nan` checkpoint to start your debugging.

Comment: tfdebugger doesn't work in windows; it can't even be imported....I'm on latest gpu version.