# How to use tf.check_numerics

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning

I am trying to use `tf.check_numerics` (TensorFlow 1.2) to prevent `NaN` in my gradients, inspired by [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40701712/how-to-check-nan-in-gradients-in-tensorflow-when-updating). My code is:

```
optimizer = tf.train.RMSPropOptimizer(learning_rate, decay=0.99)
grads_and_vars = optimizer.compute_gradients(graph.loss_total)
grads, variables = zip(*grads_and_vars)
clipped_gradients, _ = (tf.clip_by_global_norm(grads, 1.))

grad_check = tf.check_numerics(clipped_gradients, 'check_numerics caught bad gradients')
     # ^ this line causes an error
with tf.control_dependencies([grad_check]):
    graph.train_op = optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(clipped_gradients, variables))
```

But I get the error message:

```
ValueError: Tried to convert 'tensor' to a tensor and failed. Error: Shapes must be equal rank, but are 2 and 1
    From merging shape 2 with other shapes. for 'training/CheckNumerics/packed' (op: 'Pack') with input shapes: [4,16], [16], [16,2], [2].
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

`clipped_gradients` is a list. Try

```
grad_check = tf.check_numerics(clipped_gradients[0], 'check_numerics caught bad gradients')
```